# Importing a nix file results in an error of anonymous function called with unexpected argument 'system'

Tags: nix

I'm trying to set a variable to the result of a function defined in an external file.

Within my nixos config I have something like:

```
let 
  phpFile = import ./tgsend.nix (pkgs);
in
{
...
}
```

Where `phpFile = import ./tgsend.nix (pkgs);` is the new line I added. Calling this function results in an error of:

> error: anonymous function at /etc/nixos/tgsend.nix:1:1 called with
> unexpected argument 'system'
>
> ```
>    at /etc/nixos/services.nix:8:13:
>
>         7|   myxmonad = import sources.XMonadLayouts {}; #
>         8|   phpFile = import ./tgsend.nix (pkgs);
>          |             ^
>         9|   in (use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

The contents of `tgsend.nix` is:

```
{pkgs}: pkgs.writeText "test.php" "<?php echo 'hello world'; "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to resolve this, but the core of the issue is that you are calling a function with more arguments that required

```hs
{pkgs}: pkgs.writeText
```

This line means, a function is accepting an attribute set argument with a property `pkgs` (attribute set is a dictionary/map). It cannot have anything more (if you want more, should use `{pkgs, ...}`

There is a standard way to declare functions that require items from `pkgs` however which is `pkgs.callPackage`

Example with repl:

```hs
nix-repl> pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}
nix-repl> myPackage = { lib }: lib.strings.toLower "HELLO WORLD"
nix-repl> pkgs.callPackage myPackage {}
"hello world"
```

`callPackage` will inject any dependencies in the `pkgs` for you and the second argument is for overrides.
In your example it can be changed as follows:

tgsend.nix

```hs
{ writeText }: 
  writeText "test.php" "<?php echo 'hello world'; "
```

```hs
let 
  phpFile = pkgs.callPackage (import ./tgsend.nix) {};
in
{
...
}
```

Comment: Good to hear about callPackage. I have a question though about "There is a standard way to declare functions that require items from pkgs" - it's not to clear how this occurs? Does it basically bring `pkgs` into scope for the function?

Comment: no it won't bring `pkgs` into scope. you'll define the function that requires access to attributes under `pkgs` by simply having them as arguments, similar to example above with `writeText`. 
Then you call these functions by using `pkgs.callPackage`. You must have `pkgs` in scope at this point (from many different ways that you can import pkgs). This has the benefit of allowing overlays and overrides to be passed in and used as well

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `tgsend.nix` file to instead be:

`{pkgs, ...}: pkgs.writeText "test.php" "<?php echo 'hello world'; "`

Essentially adding `,...` to the function parameters. Not quite sure why this solves this though... Possibly something to do with https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/nixpkgs-parameters.html#idm140737319673792

---

Alternatively as mentioned in @BlackBeans comment: `pkgs: pkgs.writeText "test.php" "<?php echo 'hello world'; "` also works

Comment: This works because you are passing `pkgs` to the function, which is a set containing a lot of things, among which an attribute also called `pkgs` (which basically refers to itself). So `{pkgs}: something` creates a function that requires a set which only has an attribute `pkgs`, whereas `{pkgs, ...}: something` creates a function that takes a set which has, among other things, an attribute called `pkgs`. But, in your case, the right thing to do would simply be `pkgs: something`, because you are passing `pkgs` already.

Comment: Okay that explains it. I think I just confused myself with {} being part of the syntax for function parameters but it's actually not - it's an attribute set instead.